# How many sharps in G Dorian Minor?

Tags: scales, modes, accidentals

How many sharps are in G Dorian Minor? I believe that there aren't any but I am not sure. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

G Dorian is G Dorian, not minor.  That said: G Dorian has one flat (Bb) and no sharps, although the seventh F is occasionally sharped as an accidental.

Comment: ...and the sixth E is often flatted in descent (which was standard _musica ficta_ for Dorian). Baroque theoreticians tended to consider Dorian mode as the precursor to minor.

Comment: @Patrx2- true. But the pure Dorian mode is still quite common in folk music and jazz.

Comment: I'm not sure it's exactly fruitful to use earlier music to describe Modes, since the actual use of modes since then has changed.  The Baroque era was the time in which functional harmony was solidified, so the use of 7 and b6 would reflect the transition to functional harmony more than the use of the Mode, in my opinion at least.  Most Modal music beyond Baroque tends to stick to the scale much more.  Adding the leading tone may be useful in solidifying the resolution to tonic at the end of a piece but once you begin regularly using it, the texture changes to a less than Modal sound.